# Finding numbers in text and displaying them

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, decimal

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal x = 0;

    if (Decimal.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out x))
    {
        var y = 1000000;
        var answer = x * y;

        displayLabel2.Text = x.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        displayLabel2.Text = "error";
    }
}
```

In my code if the user types in 7.2 it will display 7.2. And if you type in 0.72 it will display it as so. And so on. I am trying to only take the 2 digits that aren't 0 though. I need it inputted as a decimal for a conversion. But I then need to take the 2 main numbers and display it. so if I type in 0.00072, I only need to display 72.

The catch is, if I type in 0.001 or 0.0010, I need to display 10. I have no idea where to start with this. I tried using length to find the numbers, but because I am using decimals, I cannot use "Length".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
displayLabel2.Text=(x.ToString().Replace(".","").TrimStart(new Char[] {'0'})+"00").Substring(0,2) ;
```

Comment: I need to use something else, because decimal doesnt contain TrimStart

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the "ToString()". Code is now updated.

Comment: Thanks this worked like a charm. Do you happen to know how I could now count the amount of zeroes before the decimal? I mean like after I multiply my x * y. Once I multiply those, I get answer. Now I need to count how many 0s there are before the decimal. Like if I have 72000.00. I need to display 3 because there are 3 zeroes before

Comment: first get the integer part of x using _int y =(int)x_, then count the trailing zeros of y in a loop. _int count=0 ; while (y!=0) { if ( (y=y/10) != 0) count++ }_

Answer (score 2):

That you want is to trim the leading zeros. This can be done like below:

```
var trimmedValue = x.ToString(CutlureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                    .TrimStart(new Char[] {'0'});
if(trimmedValue.Length == 1) trimmedValue = trimmedValue+"0";
displayLabel2.Text = trimmedValue;
```

Comment: This seems to need a bit more, namely that 0.001 is supposed to output "10"

Comment: You are correct :) I didn't address this case. I will update my post.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I think that now is ok.

Comment: I need to use something else, because decimal doesnt contain TrimStart

Comment: You could just use the `ToString()` method.